# Hashing the content of webservice response to check differences

Tags: c#, web-services, md5

I call a SOAP webservice in this way:

```
WSStatus.WSClient ws = new WSStatus.WSClient();
I = ws.stats(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["USR"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PWD"], "aCode");
```

Every time I invoke this webservice it can give me a different output, so I need to check if that output is the same of the previous call. The output is not a string so I can't check it in a simple way but I need something clever. Any ideas?

I would have something like an MD5 hash, so I could store it in a database for future check.

Comment: What is the output of the service call? Is it an object? Do you have access to the implementation of that object? How do you define "not the same" on that object?

Comment: The output is an XML tree...

Comment: Is it your own web-service or by third-party?

Comment: I would parse the XML into an object in which you can implement IComparable. Save the latest parsed object received and compare each time with the parsed result.

Comment: 3rd party webservice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are returning an ordinary object, you can try to serialize the response on a byte array and generate the object hash with the MD5 or SHA256 (less collisions detected according to Wikipedia). This code might help you.

```
    public static string GetObjectHash<T>(this T foo)
    {
        byte[] serializedData = null;
        var hasher = SHA256.Create();
        var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T));

        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            serializer.WriteObject(stream, foo);
            serializedData = stream.ToArray();
        }

        serializedData = hasher.ComputeHash(serializedData);

        return String.Concat(serializedData.Select(d => d.ToString("x2")));
    }
```

I hope this helps!